# Non-linear population projections

Tags: epidemiology

First of all, I apologize if the english isn't too clear as it is not my first language.

I'm an engineering student who does a lot of computer science and statistics. However what I learn in statistics isn't very theoretical. It's more so, learning how to implement statistical methods with a computer.

Right now as a part of my internship, I'm doing a study on meningitis and disease mapping. I had to calculate standardized incidence ratios (SIR) and then apply a smoothing method in order to have more robust/statistically significant SIRs. However to do that, I need the population data for my study period, and a few years are lacking.

The easiest way to estimate the population for those years is doing a linear interpolation, however it doesn't produce very good results. The methods I have seen on the internet involve using very complicated equations with parameters concerning the amount of deaths, birth, etc. (I also do not have that data).

Do you know methods of estimating a population that would be doable by someone who doesn't necessarily have a big knowledge of theoretical statistics and that would produce a better result than linear interpolation?

Comment: Gibbs sampling may be a good option to try but there are a lot work to set up though.

Comment: How do you compute the statistical significance for smoothed ratios?

Comment: I count on doing it with Winbugs (bayesian method). But since I can't calculate SIRs  I haven't gotten around to doing it just yet

Comment: Thank you two for responding by the way. I'll look into gibbs sampling.